# how do I create a simple text with one variable in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

I have zero experience in programming and such, but I would like to create on my website something like that: the user would write his name (on a form or something), and that after clicking on a button the website delivers a text which includes the name he wrote. The text is always the same, the only thing that changes is the name.
Is there an easy way, maybe a plugin, to achieve this? Thank you very much, cheers

Comment: Can you explain more  by example?

Comment: sure: let's say we have this text : "xxxxx goes to bed". I would like to have a query where the user writes its name, (es: john), so that the initial text becomes "john goes to bed". it's like concatenate function in excel, sort of, but I don't know how to translate it in wordpress. I hope it is clear enough. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf()`, it will replace `%s` to variable content

```
$may_name = 'john';
echo sprintf(__("%s goes to bed", 'text_domain'), $may_name);
```

Comment: that's great! problem is: now i need a textbox with a submit button. so that the user writes its name in the box, click on submit and get the personalized text (that is "xxx goes to bed"). is it too difficult to create? i dont want to bother you too much. thanks again